# How is livewire loading targets supposed to be setup?

Tags: laravel, laravel-livewire

In a livewire blade file I have the following code:

```
<div wire:loading.remove wire:target="runAudit" >
  Not running audit
</div>
<div wire:loading wire:target="runAudit">
  running audit
</div>

<button wire:click.prevent ="$emit('runAudit', {{ $item }})"  title='Run Audit'><i class="fas fa-play"></i></button>
```

The controller is simple:

```
class Audit extends Component
{
    protected $listeners = ['runAudit'];      
    public $item;


    public function runAudit(Item $item)
    {        
        sleep(2);
        $this->item = $item;
        dump($item);
    }

    public function render()
    {       
        return view('livewire.audit-list');
    }
}
```

If I remove the `wire:target="runAudit"` the code works as desired - but I want the target there to prevent it from being executed on other actions.  With it in place the page doesn't update as expected.

Am I missing something?

Answer (score 0):

`wire:target="runAudit"` should be added only in in elements with `wire:loading`, remove it from the element having `wire:loading.remove`.

Comment: I don't think that was the issue.  I found that if I called the function directly things worked as I had expected.  The $emit function however treated things differently and the target was ignored/not working.  I'm not sure if this is by design or a bug (seems like a bug in livewire)

Comment: did you try to emit the function with js in console and it returned to undefined?

Comment: No, @moghwan, but I got passed my hump by using the direct call rather than emit:

<button wire:click.prevent ="runAudit ({{$item}} )"...>
vs
<button wire:click.prevent ="$emit('runAudit', {{ $item }})"...>